# Make a list from one OR many string values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, list, geopandas

I have one data frame that has resulted from a spatial join between 2 Geopandas.GeoDataFrame objects.

Because there was more than one item overlapping with the target feature, the rows have been duplicated so that each row has the inherited information from each of the overlapping entities. To simulate this situation, we can run the following lines:

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

cities = cities[['geometry', 'name']]
cities = cities.rename(columns={'name':'City'})

countries_with_city = geopandas.sjoin(world, cities, how="inner", op='intersects')
```

I am trying to generate a new column in the world geodaframe that contains a list of length 0,1 or +1, with the `"City"` attribute of all the overlapping cities of each country. For this, I wrote this so far:

```
for country in world.index:
    subset_countries = countries_with_city.loc[countries_with_city.index==world.loc[country, "name"]]
    a = subset_countries["City"].tolist()
    list_of_names = list(subset_countries["City"])
    world[list_of_names]=list_of_names
```

When I run this code, however, I get stuck at the line `a = subset_countries["City"].tolist()`. The error I get is `'str' object has no attribute 'tolist'`.

According to what I have tested and investigated, it seems that I am getting this error because the first country [`countries_with_city.loc[countries_with_city.index==world.loc[1, "name"]]`] has only one city inside of it. Hence, when I slice the dataframe, there fact that there is only one row with index=1 makes the outcome a string, instead of data frame that can then be listed.

Is there a straightforward way I can use so that the code works in any case? (when there are 0, 1 and many cities). The goal is to generate a list of city names that will then be written in the world dataframe.

I am working on python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, one approach is to build a mapping from country name to a list of city names:

```
# Build a Series with index=countries, values=cities
country2city = countries_with_city.groupby('name')['City'].agg(lambda x: list(x))

# Use the mapping on the name column of the world DataFrame
world['city_list'] = world['name'].map(county)

# Peek at a nontrivial part of the result
world.drop('geometry', axis=1).tail()
        pop_est continent          name iso_a3  gdp_md_est                                          city_list
172    218519.0   Oceania       Vanuatu    VUT       988.5                                                NaN
173  23822783.0      Asia         Yemen    YEM     55280.0                                            [Sanaa]
174  49052489.0    Africa  South Africa    ZAF    491000.0  [Cape Town, Bloemfontein, Johannesburg, Pretoria]
175  11862740.0    Africa        Zambia    ZMB     17500.0                                           [Lusaka]
176  12619600.0    Africa      Zimbabwe    ZWE      9323.0                                           [Harare]
```

If you intend to print the city lists right away, you can join the strings in each list to remove the square brackets:

```
world['city_str'] = world['city_list'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(c for c in x)
                                             if x is not np.nan else None)

# Sanity-check result
world.filter(like='city').tail()
                                             city_list                                         city_str
172                                                NaN                                             None
173                                            [Sanaa]                                            Sanaa
174  [Cape Town, Bloemfontein, Johannesburg, Pretoria]  Cape Town, Bloemfontein, Johannesburg, Pretoria
175                                           [Lusaka]                                           Lusaka
176                                           [Harare]                                           Harare
```